# React native 'Cannot read property of undefined' AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I try to load the ID from a ble device via AsyncStorage that I save in a another component. But then I do this I get the following error:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:65 Cannot read property 'loadMac' of undefined
```

This is my loadMac() function:

```
   export function loadMac() {
  AsyncStorage.getItem(MAC_KEY)
    .then((item) => {
      console.log(item);
      return item;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

And I call this function in my component like this:

```
store.loadMac();
```

Then I try

```
AsyncStorage.getItem(MAC_KEY)
  .then((item) => {
      console.log(item)});
```

I will get my ID.. but not from my function that I have in another file.

Any solution ?

Comment: store is not defined when you are calling `store.loadMac();`

Comment: you've not shown how store would be possibly defined as anything

Comment: What is store? Did you import the function as store? If you imported the loadMac module as store, you just call store()

Comment: This is how I import my store => const store = require('../../api/store');

EDIT:

Ok sorry I forget this import in my other component <.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says store is not defined, so you should look for a solution checking it.
By the code you posted I am assuming you've tried to have 2 different components: one stateless component named 'store' which you are exporting   to access its' loadMac function. And another where you are importing the 'store' component. Correct me if I'm wrong.
If this is the case, your export syntax is incorrect. It should be something similar to this

```
export default const Store = () => {...}
```

And then import it like this:

```
import Store from './yourPathToStore';
```

If it's not, then you shouldn't have that `export` and also clarify what is exactly your 'store'.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Jeah you right, I forget the import, had this only in one component <.<